# Magento 2 colour swatches not showing on homepage

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, color-swatches, magento2.2.3

I have used Magento's default feature for calling New products on homepage. In  the list I have a configurable product with visual swatches. But the visual swatches not showing on homepage, can anyone suggest the best way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it myself:-

Created a block file:-
and add the following class in my constructor

```
\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productsCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $reportsCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed\Proxy $viewedProductsBlock,
        array $data = [],
         \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable $listConfigurable
```

Created the function `getProductDetailsHtml`

and rewrote it like:-

```
public function getProductDetailsHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $renderer =  $this->_listConfigurable;

        if ($renderer) {
            $renderer->setProduct($product);
            return $renderer->setTemplate('product/listing/renderer.phtml')->toHtml();
        }
        return '';
    }
```

Then in my template file that I set in my `Block.php` file, passed product object:-

```
<?php echo $this->getProductDetailsHtml($product); ?>
```