# Magento2: How to display most view product collection in home page?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7.2

I need to display product collection in home page in magento2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Layout file:

```
<container name="home.lookbook" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="lookbook-block home-cards">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="lookbook"
                       template="Magento_Theme::html/home/lookbook.phtml"/>
            </container>
```

In Template file:

```
<?php
$collection = $this->getProductDetails();
$productCollection = $collection['collection'];
$categoryName = $collection['name'];
if (count($productCollection)) {
    ?>
    <div class="shy-block mgb20 product-recently">
        <div class="most-viewed">
            <div class="lg-title">
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $categoryName; ?>
            </div>

            <div class="product-carousel" data-mage-init='{"viewPageSlickCarousel": {}}'>

                <?php
                foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
                    $productName = $product->getName();
                    $productUrl = $block->productRender($product);
                    $templateType = \OX\ProductReview\Block\Product\ReviewRenderer::STAR_VIEW;
                    $image = 'upsell_products_list';
                    ?>
                    <?php if ($product->isSaleable()): ?>

                        <div class="product-carousel-item text-center">
                            <div class="product-carousel-item-image">
                                <!--To display Product label -->
                                <?php
                                $productAttributeCode = $this->getAttributeCode($product);
                                if (!empty($productAttributeCode)) {
                                    $attributeOptionlabel = $product->getAttributeText($productAttributeCode);
                                    if (!empty($attributeOptionlabel)) {
                                        $attributeOptionText = strtolower($attributeOptionlabel);
                                        $optionLabel = str_replace(" ", "-", $attributeOptionText);
                                        $mediaUrl = $block->getMediaUrl();
                                        $productLabelUrl = $mediaUrl . 'attribute/options/' . $optionLabel . '.png';
                                        ?>                                        
                                        <div class="product-label shy-product-label">
                                            <img src="<?php echo $productLabelUrl ?>" alt="<?php echo $optionLabel ?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                                <!-- To display Product label  End -->

                                <a href="<?= $productUrl ?> ">
                                    <?= $block->getImage($product, $image)->toHtml(); ?>
                                </a>
                                <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($product, $templateType) ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="product details product-carousel-item-details">
                                <div class="product-carousel-item-name">
                                    <a class="" href="<?= $productUrl ?>">
                                        <?= $productName ?>                        
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($product) ?>
                                <div class="product-carousel-item-inner">
                                    <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                        <div class="actions-primary">
                                            <?php $controller = $block->getUrl('ajaxcart/index/productdata/') ?>
                                            <form data-product-type="<?= /* @NoEscape */ $product->getTypeId() ?>" data-role="tocart-form"  data-url="<?php echo $controller ?>"  data-product-name="<?= /* @NoEscape */ $product->getName() ?>" data-product-sku="<?= /* @NoEscape */ $product->getSku() ?>" action="<?= $block->getUrl("checkout/cart/add") ?>" method="post" >
                                                <input type="hidden" value="<?= $product->getId() ?>" name="product">
                                                <input type="hidden" value="<?= $block->getEncodeUrl() ?>" name="uenc">
                                                <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                                <button type="submit" 
                                                        title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                        class="action tocart primary">
                                                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                </button>
                                            </form>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--- Item end -->
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    endif;
                }
            }
            ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
    "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
    "productInfoPopup": {}
    }
    }
</script>

<div id="product-popup"> </div>
```

And also refer [Magento 2 colour swatches not showing on homepage](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217582/magento-2-colour-swatches-not-showing-on-homepage)